# In React, when I'm adding a new item in an array of objects, it gets rendered, but the onClick event won't trigger, why is that?

Tags: reactjs, onclick

I'm building a link list, and I have a list of objects that represent sub-categories.

They're rendered that way:

```
subCategories.map(subCat => (
<CustomLinkWrapper>
 <CheckboxWrapper
  onClick={() => findAndToggleLinkInModal(link.name)}
 >
 <ModalCheckbox
  aria-label={`Select ${link.name}`}
  value={link.name}
  isChecked={link.checked}
  theme={theme}
 />
 <StackedText>
   <div>
    <p>Link name</p>                                                        
    {link.name}
   </div>
   <div>                                                            
    <p>URL</p>
    <Tooltip label={link.link}>{link.link}</Tooltip>
  </div>
 </StackedText>
</CheckboxWrapper>
<TripleDot
  ref={anchorRef}
  onClick={() => {
   setAddNewLink(false);
   handleTogglePopover(link.name, link.url, link.name);
  }}
>
 ...
</TripleDot>
<PopoverDialog
 aria-labelledby="linkActions"
 anchorRef={anchorRef}
 isOpen={isPopoverOpen}
 onClose={handleTogglePopover}
 placement={'auto'}
>
<List>
 <ListItem
  size={'big'}
  before={<Icon icon={mdiFileEdit} />}
  onItemSelected={handleClickEditOwnLink}
 >
  Edit the link
 </ListItem>
 <ListItem
  size={'big'}
  before={<Icon icon={mdiFileRemove} />}
  onItemSelected={() => {
   console.log('test');
   removeLinkFromOwnLink(link.name);
  }}
 >
   Remove the link
 </ListItem>
</List>
</PopoverDialog>
</CustomLinkWrapper>
))
```

They have an onItemSelected() prop that should trigger on click. It works initially when the page renders, and the list is its first own version. But when I add a new item to the list, both `<ListItem />`'s onItemSelected don't work. I have no idea why, I've been on it for a day or so and it's getting frustrating.

I've tried adding an `onClickEdit` property to the links, because maybe on render, the `onClick` just wasn't present. But it didn't work. The `onClick` on the `<TripleDot />` is working fine, but not the `onClick` on the `<ListItem />`, so it didn't change much.

Initially that code was in the main file with all the functions, but I thought maybe it wasn't rendering properly, so I copied/pasted the code to a child component, but it didn't work either.

Comment: `onItemSelected` dont work - even console logs you added are not logged? Any errors you see in the console? Also, `.map` function should return 1 element (Node), so all the things inside you have should be wrapped by "something", like `<> ... </>` [fragment wrapper](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) (with `keys` due to map) at least, and im seeing you are trying to return 2 "root nodes" (TripleDot + PopoverDialog). Or did i miss something?

Comment: No the console.log() doesn't work. No errors, nothing. Yeah sorry I didn't want to put the whole snippet, but there's a parent component, I'll try to edit the original post with the code context, my bad

Comment: Ok, then I guess the part of code you shared is ok, and `ListItem` component itself needs some investigations. Any way to see what is it?

Comment: `ListItem` is a component from a UI package I'm using, it's not something custom made

Comment: Is it a common one? Or we can see it on NPM and check docs/issues on github? Asking because it is still a `custom component`, and `onClick` you tried to pass to it will only work if it is handled inside of it, for custom components this onClick is just a prop which could be completely ignored. And any errors thrown from inside of it could be halted inplace without rethrowing, etc. I mean if everything works, even the TripleDot you mentioned - probably something wrong is happening inside of that component. Asuming even console logs are not working.

Comment: Nope it's one made by my client, might be a fork of something else, but yeah maybe that's coming from here. The TripleDot is a div though. I'm using styled components and TripleDot is basically a styled div. But I see your point, I'll try in a few seconds to just ad a new empty <div> with a silly onClick and see if it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250871/discussion-between-mael-landrin-and-sergey-sosunov).